# camel Spring DSL onException doesn't fire at all

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I am using the Camel DSL Spring route as reported below.
As you can see, I want to convert an `xls` file and if an exception occurs I need to log an error and move file in a specific folder.
It seems none of these steps happen, I just got an exception when converting the file and got a `moveFailed` of "file" component .
I suspect the exception mechanism does not transpose the handled flag and then the exception returns to caller , the file comp, and it proceeds with the moving.

How do I execute `onException` mechanism on exception

```
<route>
        <from uri="file:C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HB_DATA/mov?delay=1000&amp;move=../mov_done&amp;moveFailed=../mov_fail"/>
        <process ref="processor"/>
        <to uri="bean:excelConverter"/>
        <onException>
            <exception >org.savino.hb.dataprovider.DataProviderException</exception>

            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <log loggingLevel="ERROR" message="HEY I GOT AN EXCEPTION" /> 

            <to uri="file:C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HB_DATA/mov_fail?fileName={header.X_UID}"/>
            <process ref="processorEx"/>
        </onException>
        <to uri="bean:finish"/>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<onException>` has to **precede** the code that is eager to run in error.
In your particular case, just move the exception handling immediately after the 'from', eg:

```
<route>
      <from uri="..."/>
        <!-- Exception handling -->
        <onException>
          <exception>org.savino.hb.dataprovider.DataProviderException</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <log loggingLevel="ERROR" message="HEY I GOT AN EXCEPTION" /> 
        <onException>
        <!-- The route definition -->
        <process ref="processor"/>
        <to uri="bean:excelConverter"/>
        <to uri="file:..."/>
        <to uri="bean:finish"/>
    </route>
```

A possible (more natural) alternative is a try-catch:
http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/try-catch-finally.html